# DateTime("2019-08-07T19:20-5:00") conversion to local date time with offset value

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I get the datetime content in the below string format with offset time value from the source system.

```
2019-08-07T19:20-5:00
```

Where I want to convert that into date time using the offset value. I tried the below, but not getting the expected result.

```java
OffsetDateTime sourceDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-08-07T19:20-5:00"); 
System.out.println(sourceDateTime.getOffset());
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-08-07T19:20-5:00' could not be parsed at index 16
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at java.base/java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:387)
    at com.example.demo.Testfile.main(Testfile.java:19)
```

Is there any simple way to the expected output?

Note: I am using Java 8

Comment: It seems T19:20-5:00 isn't valid format

Comment: As tapsshore has shown, the offset needs to have a double digit hour.

Comment: To parse the string you received, you need to use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use an ISO formatter if you don't get an ISO `String`…
The problem seems to be the format of the offset you get, it is `+H:mm` instead of the one used in the ISO standard, that is `+HH:mm`. In words: *It does not consider single-digit hours*.

You will have to build a specific `DateTimeFormatter` for this situation.

Unfortunately, **Java 8 does not support patterns with a single-digit representation of offset hours**, but if you can use Java 9 or higher, you'll be able to define a `DateTimeFormatter` that considers zone offsets formatted as `+H:mm`:

### Java 9+

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                                    .appendOffset("+H:mm", "UTC")
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    OffsetDateTime sourceDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-08-07T19:20-5:00", dtf);
    System.out.println(sourceDateTime.getOffset());
}
```

This uses the ISO formatter for a `LocalDateTime` and appends a specific pattern for parsing offsets.

Admittedly, I'm not sure if `"UTC"` is a good (hard-coded) choice as a default offset in case the `String` does not contain any.

Output of this code:

```
-05:00
```

---

### Java 8 --> `String` manipulation

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide some variants of input
    List<String> variants = List.of(
            "2019-08-07T19:20-5:00", "2019-08-07T19:20+5:00",
            "2019-08-07T19:20-05:00", "2019-08-07T19:20+05:00"
    );
    
    // handle offset extraction via String manipulation for each variant
    variants.forEach(variant -> {
        String parseable = variant;
        /*
         * This assumes an offset always has a sign and 
         * a colon that separates hours and minutes.
         *
         * Get all their indexes in order to find the offset
         */
        int lastIndexOfColon = variant.lastIndexOf(':');
        int lastIndexOfMinus = variant.lastIndexOf('-');
        int lastIndexOfPlus = variant.lastIndexOf('+');
        
        /*
         * Decide which sign actually leads the offset
         * (it's either a plus or the very last minus).
         * In either case insert a leading zero if the amount of digits/chars
         * between '-'/'+' and ':' is 1, otherwise don't do anything…
         */
        if (lastIndexOfMinus > lastIndexOfPlus && lastIndexOfMinus + 2 == lastIndexOfColon) {
            parseable = variant.substring(0, lastIndexOfMinus + 1) 
                        + '0' 
                        + variant.substring(lastIndexOfMinus + 1);
        } else if (lastIndexOfPlus + 2 == lastIndexOfColon) {
            parseable = variant.substring(0, lastIndexOfPlus + 1)
                        + '0'
                        + variant.substring(lastIndexOfPlus + 1);   
        }
        // then parse the manipulated String
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(parseable);
        // get the offset
        ZoneOffset zoneOffset = odt.getOffset();
        // and print some result
        String msg = String.format("%s has an offset of %s", variant, zoneOffset);
        System.out.println(msg);
    });
}
```

The output of this example is

```
2019-08-07T19:20-5:00 has an offset of -05:00
2019-08-07T19:20+5:00 has an offset of +05:00
2019-08-07T19:20-05:00 has an offset of -05:00
2019-08-07T19:20+05:00 has an offset of +05:00
```

Another way could be to separate the offset part from the date and time and create a `ZoneOffset.of(int, int)` using parsed values left and right to the last colon. Parsing the date-time part and applying the offset afterwards could also lead to the desired result.

Comment: I found it in the docs of Java 8 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), but I admit, I didn't test it on Java 8, I used Java 11…

Comment: Oh, it's the pattern… I was thinking the method hadn't been available in Java 8, but it was the pattern for single-digit hours. My fault…

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for your suggestions, I added a custom solution for Java 8 using `String` manipulation in order to add a leading zero if necessary. Looks ugly, but seems to be working ^^

Comment: Fine (and +1). I could have been tempted to something like `String parseable = variant.replaceFirst("(.*[-+])(\\d):", "$10$2:");`; but it's still uglier than yours! Good that many of us have Java 9 or later. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still unsure if a regex is faster… if it is, I may be fine with ugly code ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246369/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-dehaar).

Answer (score -3):

This is the correct code

```
OffsetDateTime sourceDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-08-07T19:20-05:00");
System.out.println(sourceDateTime.getOffset());
```

Comment: Please point out the difference ("-05:00" vs "-5:00") explicitly. That said, I don't think this is a very helpful answer if OP gets their information as shown and cannot change the source system to produce a different format.

Comment: I think changing the input is not the answer OP wanted to read because OP may be unable to change it.